# Laravel 5 CSRF on prod server, not dev

Tags: php

I develop locally with `Laravel Homestead` and then have a remote server I push to for production. On my local copy, everything works with no issues. On the prod, I get a Token Mismatch exception on any route I try, even if I curl a page in the server.

I've been searching around for two days now trying to figure out what could cause this and I've had absolutely no luck. I think it may just be a server configuration issue, but I have no idea what would prevent that from working properly. I just cannot figure this out.

`/storage` has the proper permissions (777 at the moment), the config files have unique session variables, and my .env is currently using 'file' for the session driver. This happens with 'database' as the driver as well though.

If I do `hhvm public/index.php` or `php public/index.php` it works as expected, no CSRF issues.

Comment: we're going to need to see some code..

Comment: It happens with a base install of Laravel 5 as well. Not sure what code would help here exactly.

Comment: Is your session ID changing from pageview to pageview?

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes it was, however it was due to a server configuration error. I submitted an answer explaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging, it turns out the solution was pretty simple. HHVM and Nginx were running under the wrong user. I set them both back to www-data and the problem was resolved.